# Strange HTTP 414 request captured by IDS

Tags: apache, http, http-status-codes, alerts

My ids is generating so many HTTP 414 requests i.r content Uri is too large, the interesting part is, all these requests are sending from my server to and external IP. I look into Apache and error logs , I couldn't find anything related to 414 status code. even my ids doesn't give much info other than the fallowing info

```
HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Large
 Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u8 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/
 1.0.1e
 Vary: Accept-Encoding
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 23:02:47 GMT
 X-Varnish: 213113893
 Age: 0
 Via: 1.1 varnish
 Connection: keep-alive
 X-Cache: MISS
 Content-Length: 250

 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
 <title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>
 <p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
 limit for this server.<br />
 </p>
 </body></html>
```

I just want know what my server wants to send? Is it a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain your server generates these requests? If it does, you should also be able to figure out what the target server is. Does it hit many external IP's randomly? This should tell you a lot more.

This could be the behavior of a worm that infected your server, and is attempting to find other broken servers. `Request-URI too large` makes it likely that it's attempting to trigger some buffer overflow based on the URI. I believe there were several security problems related to that some time ago.

At the very least I've seen a lot of attempts such as those on my own servers in my access log. But then it was other infected servers trying to break into mine, not my servers reaching out.

Comment: Event thanks for the reply, the problem is I haven't seen any sort of information related to 414 error on my Apache logs. when it come to the external IPs yes, everyday around my ids is generating alerts that saying that couple of my servers are trying to send this type of requests. Even I checked my varnish load balancer logs , if found nothing. you are saying there were some security problems in the past , would you please give me some info about that?

Comment: You should start figuring out which application on your server sends these requests. Finding a list of vulnerabilities that exploit buffer overflows in http requests is not going to do you any good.

Really, if you think that this is the issue, you need to disconnect that machine from the net. Stack overflow not a good place for broad questions like this.